# Gtk conversion to html

Tags: gtk, semantics, ui-design, gui-designer, web-application-design

In order to have a OS with a uniform interface, allowing better mutual interoperabilities, I'm looking for a way to build a system in which all interface would be in html5.

For example, starting from the gtk library (in order to use the existing), it could be possible to translate code such as:

```
gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window1), "the title");
```

in

```
document.title = "the title"
```

I would like to know if there were any tools that could help me achieve this goal

**edit**

to clarify my question, and let understand what I'm looking for, I found this [study](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDkQFjAA&url=http://www.mpi-sws.org/~neelk/icfp11-krishnaswami-benton.pdf&ei=y5w5UczdMcGjPZOTgagO&usg=AFQjCNF69s9g108kYOoY7xWGv1zUvg14cA&sig2=f-MisVkYKjmlwc3Vm5pGHA)

The first step may be to use/build a semantic ontology of what is formerly an ui. Then I could integrate the gtk library (or another desktop gui library) and the web interface languages into a same base. So I could make bijections between gtk and web methods.

I do not see that as a simple problematic, and I'm asking for ideas, tools, which could helps me.

Comment: Are you only considering looks, or the entire operations that gta can do?

Comment: All that gtk can do, ie making the interface between the system and the user.

Comment: but something which could help me to convert just a static ui is welcome!

Comment: something like Swiffy for flash https://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/

Comment: Have you seen this? http://www.geek.com/articles/news/gtk-html-5-update-puts-desktop-apps-on-the-web-20110318

Comment: yes, but I don't want to embed gtk in a web page.

Comment: checkout the gtk3 broadway backend

Comment: I've tested broadway, but I don't want to convert gtk to a canvas but to html

Comment: you are using any back end technology with html, like PHP, ASP??

Comment: I don't think that is the subject to know how the html code could be generated.

Comment: Just a side note - https://blogs.gnome.org/alexl/2011/03/15/gtk-html-backend-update/

Answer (score 4):

Once you introduce any complexity and interaction, you run into the need to convert from C\Python\Whatever-is-running-GTK into Javascript.

Your best bet is to do everything in native HTML5, have your "desktop app" be a wrapper for a web browser, which runs against (1) a remote website or (2) a local web server.  Your "desktop app" would include a small web server, and automatically select an open port on localhost.

Comment: For serving html, something like that: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/webserver could be cool. But this is not the difficult part, it could finally be better to build the interface from shell commands.

Comment: There is one very interesting application, which has followed the path Zach have recommended: pgAdmin4.

Check it out at:
https://www.pgadmin.org/development/resources/